# If a velocity vector $\vec {v(t)}$ has constant length, must its acceleration also have constant length?

Tags: physics, vectors

I'm not really sure how arbitrary acceleration is (like, if I can just choose an acceleration that makes the velocity vector erratically change directions while still keeping its length the same, or if such a thing would be called acceleration), so I've been kind of confused with this problem.

We've been learning about centripetal acceleration and circular motions in class, so that's probably related- but I don't have a clear idea how.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: I have a feeling the answer should be "no" because of the possibility mentioned in my first paragraph, but just want to confirm since I'm not really sure if I understand what it's asking

Comment: Think about constant circular motion about circles of different radii. If they all have unit speed, the acceleration vectors will differ in magnitude: $a = v^2/r = 1/r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The velocity has a constant length iff
$$
0 = \frac{d}{dt} \langle \vec v, \vec v \rangle
= 2  \left \langle \frac{d\vec v}{dt}, \vec v \right\rangle
$$hence iff the velocity is orthogonal to the acceleration. But the length of the acceleration is not constrained.